# Maxmind Geoip city encoding issue

Tags: ruby, nginx, geoip, maxmind

When configuring Max Mind with Nginx (using something like `proxy_set_header GEOIP_CITY $geoip_city;`), I get encoding issues with the city name when it has accents in it (like Montréal).

I’ve search everywhere and I can’t find an nginx switch to force utf-8 encoding. What am I missing?

I tried to `city.force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')` on ruby's side, but no dice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although it isn't documented, [it appears](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/220c36d6128bcf3e869fdd0f7767ead9a4222f08/src/http/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.c#L814) that you can force the Nginx module to use UTF-8. To use this, I believe you load the database in the following manner:

```
http {
    geoip_city            GeoLiteCity.dat  utf8;
    ...
```

Comment: What I struggle to understand is by default the legacy database returns latin-1 encoded city name. Where in the process does it gets broken? Is it because my html page is utf-8 encoded with the meta tag utf-8? Would I see the accents correctly if my page was latin1 encoded? Thanks for any insights you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `utf8_encode()` to get the results that you are trying to achieve.

For example(in php):

```
// $city_name = $record->city; 
$city_name = utf8_encode($record->city);
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that MaxMind provides a GeoIPCity API that uses UTF-8 as default charset, it appears that the GeoListeCity.dat uses **ANSI encoding**. Since some places have no translation in English, it might result in encoding confusion...

Fernando solution is working, but just in case newer versions of geoLiteCity.dat use a non ISO-8859-1 compatible charset, you might also **make sure final string is UTF-8 encoded**. For example by using `mb_convert_encoding()` (still in PHP):

```
$location->city = mb_convert_encoding($location->city, 'UTF-8');
```